# Notation issue parametric equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A curve is given parametrically by the equations $ x = 3qt^2$
, $y = 4( t^3 + 1 )$ , where $q$
is a constant. The curve meets the x-axis at $X$ and the y-axis at $Y$. Given that
$OX = 2OY$, where $O$ is the origin, find the value of $q$.

So, I've worked out that the point X is $(3q,0)$ and Y is $(0,4)$

However, I'm unsure what the notation $OX = 2OY$ means.

Comment: Do u think it is refeered to `scale` of axis?

Answer (score 1):

$OX = 2OY$ means the length of $OX $ is double the length of $OY $.

Given that  $X = (3q, 0) $, we have $OX  = |3q|$. Also $Y = (0, 4) \Rightarrow OY = 4$. Putting it all together yields $|3q| = 8$.

Comment: Oh, so OX refers to the length between the two points. Thank you, this was a silly question should have noticed.

Comment: Sure, unfortunately I have to wait 7 mins for some reason

Comment: @sdsadada i suppose it has to do with bot control and such